# Downloading file causes UI to stutter

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a service that downloads a large file inside an `AysncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method:

```
data = new byte[8192];
output = new FileOutputStream(fileLoc);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(currUrl).openConnection();
input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

While this is being executed (the file is downloading), scrolling through a `ListView` can be from a little choppy to very choppy.

I've tried creating a new process for the downloading service, changing the priority of the `doInBackground()` thread, pausing during the `while` loop for any number of milliseconds and I've optimized for memory usage.

I'm stuck and can't figure out how I could possibly make the UI not stutter while the download is occurring. The UI responds normally while the download isn't going on...

Comment: I have an app that downloads 50-100MB in the background once freshly installed, with UI updates and everything... there's no stutter in the UI. However, the UI is generally a bit twitchy when debugging. Try your code and UI responsiveness with your device disconnected from the dev machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says:

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around [`Thread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) and [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (**a few seconds** at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the `java.util.concurrent` pacakge such as [`Executor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and [`FutureTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).

So consider using a `Thread` inside your service. Or have a look at [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), it runs on a separate worker thread and does not effect the UI (to avoid of [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)). Note about `IntentService`:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only **one** request will be processed at a time.

The UI is another part. If you could provide your approach, I think maybe I could help. *For example, the Downloads extension in [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haibison.android.apps.files) is working fine till now   :-)*

Comment: I switched to IntentService from Service and it appears to have helped.  What also helped was I removed some instances of saving to the database where it wasn't completely necessary, so that sped things up a bit.  Thanks.